# Alternative Unit Testing Frameworks for SIlverlight 5 in VS 2012

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Does anyone know of a unit testing framework that is compatible with VS 2012 and Silverlight 5? I tried the Silverlight Toolkit, but it isn’t registering the new project type. Also, the toolkit’s unit testing framework is “experimental” and has some deal-breaking bugs.